# Question with Integrate and Region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

Let's say I've got a 2D region `r=Region[Polygon[{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1}}]]`. I can do integrals like `Integrate[1,{x,y}\[Element]r]`, or `Integrate[y,{x,y}\[Element]r]`, to calculate areas and area moments.

I'd like to do an integral like `Integrate[c^2,{x}\[Element]r]`, where `c` is the height (*y*max-*y*min) of the region at a particular value of *x*.

Any ideas appreciated.

-David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a height of a region as its intersection with a vertical line at $x$:

```
c[ℛ_Region][x_?NumericQ] := 
 ArcLength[RegionIntersection[ℛ, InfiniteLine[{x, 0}, {0, 1}]]]
```

Then compute its bounds and integrate:

```
ℛ = Region@Annulus[]
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = RegionBounds[ℛ];
NIntegrate[c[ℛ][x]^2, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```